# Join with time comparison

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join, count

I have a trouble getting a code working with CI especially that I need to embed a complex condition on the join
I want to extract and count information from all fields in A even though not satisfying the condition which will result in zero 0 as count

First case that works great for count

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('A.id, count(B.id) AS C');
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->join('B','B.id=A.id','left outer');
$this->db->group_by('A.id');
```

Now if I want to add a condition on a row from A that is a datetime, so that we extract all information from A AFTER a given date, and same thing, if a condition is not satisfying we return 0 :

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('A.id, count(B.id) AS C');
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->join('B','B.id=A.id','left outer');
$this->db->where('B.date >',$date);
$this->db->group_by('A.id');
```

This code is working but retruning only rows satisfying the condition and not all the other rows with 0 as count.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the where clause ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your $date in 2013-08-30 09:00:00 this format? I mean YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format?

Comment: yes it is, I extract date from mysql DATETIME format and I do the comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` is undoing the `left outer join`.  Can you do this?

```
$this->db->join('B','B.id=A.id and 'B.date >', $date, 'left outer');
```

In SQL, you would handle this by putting both conditions in the `on` statement:

```
from A left outer join
     B
     on B.id = A.id and B.date > $date;
```

Comment: I tried that too, but for somereason the date comparison is not working well, I have a count but for all rows despite having a date filter !